Django can't find leaflet admin widget.html
I want to use LeafletGeoAdmin in the Admin pages.
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin

@admin.register(Marker)
class MarkerAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "location")

When I try to add a marker, I get the error:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/my_app/marker/add/

Exception Value:  leaflet/admin/widget.html

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/me/my_map/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/forms/templates/leaflet/admin/widget.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/me/my_map/my_map/templates/leaflet/admin/widget.html (Source does not exist)
... etc ...

So it's looking for widget.html in paths of the form <many-places>/leaflet/admin/widget.html.  None of the places it's looking in has it.
By looking in .venv I did find it at
/home/me/my_map/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/leaflet/templates/leaflet/admin/widget.html

instead of at site-packages/django/forms/templates/, etc.
So I added that templates/ location with both absolute and relative paths to settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'my_app','templates'),
            '/home/me/my_map/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/leaflet/templates/',
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/leaflet/templates/')
            ],
...

But it still gives me the same error.

why does django-leaflet not know the right path, and 2) why can't Django find it at the template path I specified?


Have you set LEAFLET_CONFIG in settings.py, and added leaflet to INSTALLED_APPS ?
